# LTspice not getting exactly -3dB point

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot

Looking to answer another question on this site, to did some math and fired up LTspice to check some values and I am not able to the -3dB point.

[image]

I found the transfer function to be

$$ H(s) = \cfrac{1 + \cfrac{s}{\cfrac{1}{R_2C_1}}}{1+ \cfrac{s}{\frac{1}{(R_1+ R_2)C_1}}} $$
*This equation was corrected based off the answer that @ThePhoton had pointed out.*

Where the \$w_z = \frac{1}{R_2 C_1} = 10,000 \$ and \$ f_z = \frac{w_z}{2 \pi} = 1.592\$ kHz

The same is done for the pole

\$ w_p = 2000\$ and \$ f_p = 318.3 \$ Hz

On the plot above, I am measuring the output at R2, I have placed cursors as closely as I can get it to the \$f_p \$ and \$ f_z \$ and if we look at the magnitude I am getting -2.83 dB and -11.14 dB respectively.

It's like I am off by ~ 0.2 dB for both, because I am expected -3dB and -13.97dB.

I must be missing something. What is it ?

**edit** Adding my .asc file if anyone wants to try

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 128 64 48 64
WIRE 336 64 208 64
WIRE 336 80 336 64
WIRE 48 128 48 64
WIRE 336 208 336 160
FLAG 336 272 0
FLAG 48 208 0
SYMBOL voltage 48 112 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMBOL res 224 48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 400
SYMBOL res 352 176 R180
WINDOW 0 36 76 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL cap 320 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 1µ
TEXT 14 296 Left 2 !.ac oct 10000 1 10000
```

Comment: Try doing a sweep over a narrower frequency range, right around the frequency of interest. The values read from a plot are interpolated from the actual simulation data.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson At first I had 100 points per octave, then I changed it to 10,000 so that I have finer control. In both cases, I was still getting error. I just tried with the range between 300 and 1600, and I am still getting the ~0.20dB error.

Comment: It's been a while since I used LTspice...can you right click on the voltage source and the capacitor to make sure that LTspice didn't add some small ESR to either of those?

Comment: @efox29, even if the simulation has 10,000 points per octave, the graphing window might not display that resolution. Try narrowing the simulation frequency range (or maybe just zooming in on the graph) to see if you can position the cursors more precisely.

Comment: @ThePhoton I narrowed the window to  between 318 and 319 Hz.  The magnitude is contained between -2.836 dB and -2.849 dB.

Comment: Your transfer function can't be correct, you have a zero at w=0. The zero would need to be at least 1-2 decades past the pole for H(jwp) ~= 1/sqrt(2) (-3dB)

Comment: You should specify which terminal are you taking the output at. I think I know (because your response shows a pole and a zero) but it makes things clearer if you actually say it explicitly.

Comment: http://www.linkwitzlab.com/images/graphics/passive_down_shelf.jpg

Comment: _"It's like I am off by ~ 0.2 dB ... because I am expected -3dB"_ Swap the values of R1 and R2 and the reason will become obvious.

Comment: @sstobbe ya the numerator was incorrect. I have corrected it in the question.

Comment: For your circuit the exact -3dB coner frequancy is at $$F_C = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{C1^2(R1^2 + 2 R1 R2 - R2^2)}} = 331.861Hz$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your transfer function is not correct. You can see this must be true because your \$H(s)\$ has a pole at 0, while the actual response has the pole at ~300 Hz. I calculate

$$H(s) = \frac{1 + s(R_2C_1)}{1+s(R_1+R_2)C_1}$$

You could also write this as

$$H(s) = \frac{1+s/z}{1 + s/p}$$

where \$z = 1/R_2C_1\$ and \$p=1/\left[(R_1+R_2)C_1\right]\$.

Next, when you assume that the response is exactly -3 dB at the zero frequency, you assume that the pole is having no effect at that frequency. That is, you assume

$$1 + s(R_2C_1)\approx 1$$

But this isn't exactly true, so you don't get exactly -3 dB at the pole frequency.

Comment: This! I changed R1 to 40000 so that the separation between zero and pole was larger. When I looked at the curve, I was able to measure the predicted value to a reasonable amount. This will no doubt open up some new questions for me.

Comment: The transfer function is the same, the only difference is that I expressed it as wz and wp, such that \$ \frac{s}{w_z} \$

Comment: @efox29, it can't be the same since your version puts the pole at 0.

Comment: Yes I see it now. It was a typo on my part. It's not actually a zero. Let me fix that.

Comment: Are you sure about N(s) =  1+ s(R2C1) ?  Wouldnt it be just s(R2c1) ?

Comment: @efox29, if it were, that would put the pole at 0, which you can see from the simulation result is not correct.

Comment: Yup - you are right.